# Selecting last dynamically added textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of input boxes with dates (and the class name "newDate") in them and I can add more of them dynamically. When i try to get the value of the last added textbox, I always end up with first, which was a textbox rendered with the page.

```
$(".newDate:last-of-type").val()
```

Do I need to change my selector to catch the dynamically added textboxes or is there something else that I need to think of here? Is the location of the script with the selector relevant?

Comment: You should post more code, specifically the html and how you 'add' the new ones, you might be inserting them before in the DOM

Comment: You don't want to use last-of-type pseudo-selector with jquery. If it's sequentially the last in the list, use :last. If it's not, you may need to use some other approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the selector is run once the textboxes have been added, the following will work:

```
$(".newDate").last().val()
```

Comment: works like a charm... unsure why I looked at the "last-type-of" at all!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(":text.newDate:last").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple make sure that your class selector is specific enough to select only the elements you want, then use the :last selector instead of :last-of-type.

*Edit:* Here's a full jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9HhUJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

$('.newDate input').last().val();